# How to index into variable JSON output

Tags: python, json

A function I am using outputs `JSON` that in displays any entities present in the text is was presented with. The entity output looks like (example):

```
...
"entities": [
        {
            "end": 3,
            "entity": "pet",
            "extractor": "ner_crf",
            "processors": [
                "ner_synonyms"
            ],
            "start": 0,
            "value": "Pet"
        },
        {
            "end": 8,
            "entity": "aquatic_facility",
            "extractor": "ner_crf",
            "start": 4,
            "value": "pool"
        },
        {
            "end": 14,
            "entity": "toiletries",
            "extractor": "ner_crf",
            "start": 9,
            "value": "razor"
        }
    ],
...
```

I'm particularly interested in the `value` object. I know how to extract any arbitrary value `['entities'][i]['value']`. What I'm wondering is how do I check if a certain key-value pair is present, for example `"value": "pool"`. I don't know what their position will be since the depends on the text input, and if there are not entities in the text `"entities"` wont even be present in the `JSON`.

Comment: The structure of the `JSON` always be the same that you posted as an example, no ?

Comment: the general structure yes, however the number of entities and their order is variable

Comment: You can loop over the list of objects and check whatever to filter out the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with list comprehension like so.

```
pools = [x for x in jsondata['entities'] if x.get('value') == 'pool']
if pools:
    print("pools found")
```

The reason I'm using .get('value') rather than ['value'] is to prevent keynotfound errors being raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json module to transform the json string into python datatypes.  From here you can iterate over the dictionaries and inspect the keys for "value".

```
import json

json_str = """
[
        {
            "end": 3,
            "entity": "pet",
            "extractor": "ner_crf",
            "processors": [
                "ner_synonyms"
            ],
            "start": 0,
            "value": "Pet"
        },
        {
            "end": 8,
            "entity": "aquatic_facility",
            "extractor": "ner_crf",
            "start": 4,
            "value": "pool"
        },
        {
            "end": 14,
            "entity": "toiletries",
            "extractor": "ner_crf",
            "start": 9,
            "value": "razor"
        }
    ]
"""

data = json.loads(json_str)

values = []

for record in data:
    if "value" in record:
        values.append(record["value"])

print(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with `filter()` you can check:

```
checkThis = ['foo', 'bar']
isThere = list(filter(lambda x: 'value' in x and x['value'] in checkThis, json['entities']))
if isThere:
    print('Yes !')
else:
    print('No !')
```